# How do I follow questions and be alerted to changes/answers?

Tags: discussion, questions, bookmarks

To follow a Post you want to click the cool **Star Button**/**Favorite** button on the left just underneath the voting buttons

[image: Favorite Button]

This shows a question that I have favorited.

I want to know if there is any activity on this post.

[image: User Page]

This will have a small circle with a number in it next to the favorites, much like the responses.  This will tell me how many changes/answers have happened on my favorite questions.

I click that link/tab and...

[image: Favorites]

I need to have it opened to the Activity tab, then it will highlight the favorites that were active, and tell me who was active on those questions and when they made changes, or added an answer.

**When would I need to do this**

1. Questions that I think the OP needs to fix before I can answer
2. Questions that are closed, of which I think the OP can fix
3. Questions that I want to see answers to
4. Questions that are popular and of which I want to follow along

Comment: Shouldn't this be posted as a question and an answer? I believe FAQs on meta.SO are written that way.

Comment: @svick, I changed it once and Jamal told me it was better this way. I will look into it later.

Comment: @Malachi: I mentioned that because I couldn't tell if it was a a self-answer or not.  I also cannot quite tell what you're seeking in terms of discussion.

Comment: @Jamal, it forced me to use one of those tags.  Discussion because this came from a discussion????  figured this would be good for a FAQ or something

Comment: @Malachi: I meant discussion in general, not with the tags.  And yes, all Meta questions require [discussion], [support], [feature-request], or [bug].

Comment: @Jamal, it was more informational than anything

Comment: @Malachi: Oh, I see.  I somehow thought it was a [feature-request], even though it didn't use that tag. :-P Sorry about that.